# Как получить доступ к неименованным полям объекта

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, rxjs

Из стора в Observable приходит объект типа

```
{
 1: 'test1',
 2: 'test2',
 3: 'test3',
 4: 'test4'
 ...
}
```

Как я могу вывести в консоль значения test1, test2... не зная имена полей?

Comment: obj[1], obj[2].... и т/д/

Comment: [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let result = null;
const obj = {
  1: 'test1',
  2: 'test2',
  3: 'test3',
  4: 'test4'
}

//Вернет массив значений для полей объекта
result = Object.values(obj)
console.log(result);


//Вернет массив названий полей объекта
result = Object.keys(obj)
console.log(result);

//Доступ по имени поля (если мы его смогли узнать, например в Object.keys(obj)
result = obj['1'];
console.log(result);

result = obj[1]; // будет переведено в строку '1' и будет аналогично obj['1']
console.log(result);

// Стоит обратить внимание, что число будет переведено в строку, и не работает как индекс поля в объекте.
result = obj['0'];
console.log(result);

result = obj[0];
console.log(result);

// Поля с названием "0" не существует.
```